# Can I ask a question about the pdf format to solve a tikz issue?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I am having trouble with [tikz's way of handling colors in patterns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149144/8425). It seems that the problem is linked to the pdf code written by pgf at system level. Following [@DavidCarlisle advice](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12571403#12571403), I read some parts of the [pdf specification book](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf). But I still have some basic questions about it (googling for questions on the pdf format is not that easy...). So,

- can I ask on tex.se some questions about the pdf format (and if it's ok, should I edit my original question or create a new one)?
- if not, where should I ask?

Comment: I think questions related to output drivers, be it `pdftex`, `dvips` or whatever are perfectly ok here.

Comment: IMHO: As long as it's not about _how pdftex treats the PDF format_, but about _how does FOO works in PDF format_, they are off-topic here.

Comment: @cjorssen: Stackoverflow. The pdf experts are there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have given the necessary connection to TeX yourself. This means IMO the question is perfectly on topic here.

Although the site description explicitly mentions "Related software and tools, BibTeX, MakeIndex, Lyx, etc.", I don't think a question about PDF *as produced by `pdftex`* would be any less on topic than a question about `arara` or configuring some editor to edit `.tex` files.

Comment: Indeed. Especially since at least two experts on "PDF as produced by pdftex" are active here. :-)